# SSH connection to Github via port 443

Tags: github, ssh

I have my github keys working on port 22, a simple test like

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Returns,

> "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell
> access"

However, when I try the same with port 443, which I believe it should work,

```
ssh -vvvT git@github.com -p 443
```

I get,

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 443
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.3] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have tried many forums and online searches, but it hasn't resolved. Am I missing something? Thanks.

In past I have successfully used ssh over 443 for github pulls/pushes. Github has documention on how to use 443 for ssh here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: Did you notice the hostname you're using doesn't match the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation that you linked to](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) indicates that you can connect to a hostname of "ssh.github.com" on port 443:

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Note "ssh.github.com"
```

According to your debug output, you're connecting to "github.com", not "ssh.github.com":

```
ssh -T git@github.com
...
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.3] port 443.
                      ^^^^^^^^^^-- Note no "ssh"
```

The [second part of the page](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port#enabling-ssh-connections-over-https) describes how you can configure your ssh client so that when you tell it to connect to "github.com", it will connect to "ssh.github.com" instead. As it describes, you could add the following four lines to the end of your local `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
User git
```

Once you've done that, running a command like `ssh -T git@github.com` would actually connect to the hostname "ssh.github.com"